# PHP edit key value name in a json file

Tags: php, arrays, json, save, edit

My JSON is the following:

```
{
    "test": {
        "ASSET_NAME": "testq",
        "ENVIRONMENT": "testq",
        "APPLICATION": "testq"
    },
    "prod": {
        "ASSET_NAME": "prod1",
        "ENVIRONMENT": "prod1",
        "APPLICATION": "#N/A"
    },
    "env": {
        "ASSET_NAME": "prod2",
        "ENVIRONMENT": "Produzione",
        "APPLICATION": "prod"
    }
}
```

I need a php script to change "test" , "prod", "env" in "INFO", following the json output desired :

```
{
    "info": {
        "ASSET_NAME": "testq",
        "ENVIRONMENT": "testq",
        "APPLICATION": "testq"
    },
    "info": {
        "ASSET_NAME": "prod1",
        "ENVIRONMENT": "prod1",
        "APPLICATION": "#N/A"
    },
    "info": {
        "ASSET_NAME": "prod2",
        "ENVIRONMENT": "Produzione",
        "APPLICATION": "prod"
    }
}
```

and save it in a new json file.

is it possible?

I'm sorry copy and paste forgot a piece,

my output json would be:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y3IuE.png)

could you please show me how to convert the json source in this one?

thanks

thanks

Comment: Why would you want to make 'info' the key to 3 different sets of data? It will be very difficult to get the one you want programatically down the line. What is the purpose?

Comment: @prieber How is this comment helpful for the OP? BTW: this  is not possible as keys must be unique

Comment: There seems to be something wrong with your question. One cannot have duplicate keys. Please refer JSON structure and lookup generic questions like "How to edit JSON in php"

Comment: _...I wasn't trying to be helpful.... I gave a non-useful answer..._ Don't be 12. Also don't forget we are here only to help people @prieber

Answer (score 2):

Actually no, not really. key names must be unique, otherwise they'll get overwritten. In the result you want, if you try and get the value of $json->info, it will only return the last set. Did you mean this?

```
{
    "info" : [{
     "test": {
        "ASSET_NAME": "testq",
        "ENVIRONMENT": "testq",
        "APPLICATION": "testq"
    },
    "prod": {
        "ASSET_NAME": "prod1",
        "ENVIRONMENT": "prod1",
        "APPLICATION": "#N/A"
    },
    "env": {
        "ASSET_NAME": "prod2",
        "ENVIRONMENT": "Produzione",
        "APPLICATION": "prod"
    }]
}
```